# Android getting wrong key hash for facebook app

Tags: android, android-keystore

I am trying to get the key hash for a release keystore.

Tried below two methods which gives different key's but none works.

**Method 1:**

```
 // Add code to print out the key hash
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            <MYPACKAGE>, 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

**Method 2:**

On Windows, use:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <mykeystorelias> -keystore <keystorepath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

But method 1 worked for the debug keystore.

1. The release keystore was created by me from eclipse and don't have an extention to the name.
2. it asks for the password when I used method 2

Answer (score 0):

if you want to test the app in debug mode..please try to run following command in windows cmd

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

when prompted for password ,enter 'android'

for release version, use your release certificate that you have created via eclipse export
and run the following command in windows cmd

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <mykeystorelias> -keystore <keystorepath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

use the same password that you have used for exporting the app in eclipse

Comment: I believe, I posted the same in my question